# Firefox and ASP.NET - Escapes quotes in scripts

Tags: asp.net, firefox

Firefox alters my scripts, when I use:

```
txtEmail.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "GetNewAccountHelp('email');")
```

Chrome, IE and Safari has no problem, but Firefox outputs the following:

```
 <i>
   <input name="txtEmail" type="text" id="txtEmail" class="textboxBlack" 
       onfocus="GetNewAccountHelp(& #39;email& #39;);" />
 </i>
```

I tried doublequotes - same problem.
Firefox version: `Firefox/10.0.2`

Should i Escape the quotes in a wierd way - or?

Kind regards
  Thomas Mathiesen

Comment: mmm... I can't replicate it, and actually the html is generated server side, so it IS browser indipendent. The must be something missing in your question. Any js libs or page load event handlers?

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
txtEmail.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "GetNewAccountHelp(email)");
```

and then

```
<script>
  function GetNewAccountHelp(obj) {
      //todo
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Vatsa,
"Email" is a string, not a var.